# Exist a homeomorphic copy of $\mathcal{C}$ contained in $f(X)$. Where $\mathcal{C}=2^\mathbb{N}$.

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

If $X$ be a nonempty perfect Polish space, $Y$ a second countable space, and $f \colon X\to Y$ be injective and Baire measurable.

Question: Exist a homeomorphic copy of $\mathcal{C}$ contained in $f(X)$. Where $\mathcal{C}=2^\mathbb{N}$.

Any help I do not want to answer this question

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Alexander S. Kechris. *Classical Descriptive Set Theory*, – Springer, 1995,
[page 52](https://books.google.com/books?id=WR3SBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA52):

> **(8.38) Theorem.** Let $X$, $Y$ be topological spaces and $f\colon X\to Y$ be Baire  measurable. 
>   If $Y$ is second countable, there is a set $G\subseteq X$ that is a countable intersection of dense open sets such that $f|G$ is continuous. 
>   In particular, if $X$ is Baire, $f$ is continuous on a dense $G_\delta$-set.
>
> *Proof.* Let $\{U_n\}$ be a basis for $Y$. Then $f^{-1}(U_n)$ has the BP in $X$, so let $V_n$ be open in $X$ and let $F_n$ be a countable union of closed nowhere dense sets with 
>   $f^{-1}(U_n)\triangle V_n\subseteq F_n$. Then $G_n=X\setminus F_n$ is a countable intersection of dense open sets 
>   and so is $G=\bigcap_n G_n$.
>   Since $f^{-1}(U_n)\cap G=V_n \cap G$, $f|G$ is continuous. $\square$
>
> (8.39) Exercise. Let $X$ be a nonempty perfect Polish space, $Y$ a second countable space, 
>   and $f\colon X\to Y$ be injective and Baire measurable. 
>   Then there is a homeomorphic copy of $\mathcal C$ contained in $f(X)$.